# Looking for a Solution of "Live Search In php & storing back selected result in MYSQL dB"

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am trying to solve the following problem. I want to create a live search in PHP, retrieving Values from a dB, and storing back multiple selected values in a SQL table.

Many sites I visit today like [this](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/), but no perfect solution found.

Comment: As it stands your question is too general. You need to be more specific and should really be providing details of your attempt to solve your problem and ask a specific question about your code.

Comment: @Tristan Please see screenshots on below mentioned link:                           http://prntscr.com/9a5swm                                                                          http://prntscr.com/9a5tn3

Comment: What do you find inadequate about the solutions you mentioned? The UI, UX, or SQL?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN3IT_qYXus  Please see this you tube tutorial it will helps u...thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="find" id="find" value=""/>
<ul class="selectedItems"></ul>
$("#luogoNascita").autocomplete({
                    minLength: 3,
                    dataType: "json",
                    source: function(req, add){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { find : $("#find").val() } ,
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data.result){
                                    add(data.result);
                                }
                                else{
                                    $(this).val('');

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    if(ui.item)
                    {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(ui.item.value);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                },
                    close: function(event, ui) {

                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON($( this ).val()) || {};
                        var id = obj.id || null;
                        if (id){
                        $( this ).val(obj.selected);
                        $.post(saveUrl,{id: id},function(res){
                            console.log(res);
                        }) ;
                        }
                       $('.selectedItems')
                           .append('<li>'+obj.selected+'</li>');
                       $(this).val(''); // clear input
                    }
                });
```

//server side PHP // url.php

```
$data['result'] = array();
$data['result'][] = array(
    'label'=> 'First', 
    'value'=> json_encode(array(
        'id' => 1,
        'selected' => 'First'
    ))
);
$data['result'][] = array(
    'label'=> 'Second', 
    'value'=> json_encode(array(
        'id' => 2,
        'selected' => 'Second'
    ))
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

// server side PHP // saveUrl.php

```
$_POST['id'];
//save in DB function;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir!  But i want different functionality.                                      Please see screenshots on below mentioned link & help me out:                                                                                http://prntscr.com/9a5swm                                                                          http://prntscr.com/9a5tn3

Comment: I'm sorry , i don't understand , maybe try this if(data.result){
                                    add(data.result);$.post(saveUrl,{data: data.result},function(res){
                            console.log(res);
                        }) ;

                                }
                                else{
                                    $(this).val('');

                                } and minLength: 1,